# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/browserlaunchers/Proxies

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Environment :
Selenium version 3.6
phantom Js : 1.2.1
TestNG

Code  :
i have written a very simple code
just

```
File file = new File("D:\\study material\\Selenium Final complete\\Phantom_driver\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe"); 
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", file.getAbsolutePath());
PhantomJSDriverdriver = newPhantomJSDriver();`
```

Error :
But i am getting error

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/browserlaunchers/Proxies`

Answer (score 4):

Upgrade your phantomjsdriver to 1.3.0 version. This should solve your problem, as [stated here](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/476).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Dalton, now its working with version 1.3.0   :)
 but not with the version 1.4 or any other....
so its helpful for me.....